# No. of ways to divide an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find The number of ways to divide an array  into 3 contiguous parts such that the sum of the three parts is equal

```
-10^9 <= A[i] <= 10^9
```

My approach:
Taking Input and Checking for Base Case:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     a[i]= in.nextLong();
     sum+=a[i];
}
if(sum%3!=0)System.out.println("0");
```

If The answer is not above Then Forming the Prefix and Suffix Sum.

```
for(int i=1;i<=n-2;i++){
        xx+=a[i-1];
        if(xx==sum/3){

            dp[i]=1;
        }        
    }
```

**Suffix Sum and Updating the Binary Index Tree:**

```
for(int i=n ;i>=3;i--){
         xx+=a[i-1];
         if(xx==sum/3){
             update(i, 1, suffix);
         }
    }
```

And Now simple Looping the array to find the Total Ways:
int ans=0;

```
for(int i=1;i<=n-2;i++){

        if(dp[i]==1)
        {

            ans+=  (query(n, suffix) - query(i+1, suffix)); 
         // Checking For the Sum/3 in array where index>i+1
        }
}
```

I Getting the wrong answer for the above approach
I don't Know where I have made mistake Please Help to Correct my mistake.
Update and Query Function:

```
public static void update(int i , int value , int[] arr){

       while(i<arr.length){
           arr[i]+=value;

           i+=i&-i;

       }
}
public static int query(int i ,int[] arr){

     int ans=0;

       while(i>0){

           ans+=arr[i];
           i-=i&-i;
       }

       return ans;

}
```

Comment: in the query function you have wriiten arr+=ss[i] but arr is an array ? shouldn't it be ans+=arr[i]

Comment: @sasha sorry it's my editing mistake !!!!

Comment: could you exactly tell at which input it gives wrong ?

Comment: I don't know test cases are hidden sample input like  `3 0 3 0 3` giving me right answer

Comment: The first criterion (divisibility of the sum by 3) is not sufficient. If the input is `{3,0,3}`, the sum 6 is divisible by 3, but still the array cannot be partitioned into equal sums.

Comment: @Codor: Yes, but it is a neccessary precondition. If it fails, there is no solution.

Comment: @Codor my `else` code will give me answer 0 , i have tested you input to my code , it is giving right answer

Answer (score 3):

As far as your approach is concerned its correct. But there are some points because of which it might give WA

1. Its very likely that sum overflows int as each element can  magnitude of 10^9, so use long long .
2. Make sure that suffix and dp array are initialized to 0.

Having said that using a BIT tree here is an overkill , because it can be done in **O(n)** compared to your **O(nlogn)** solution ( but does not matter if incase you are submitting on a online judge ).
For the **O(n)** approach just take your **suffix[]** array.And as you have done mark **suffix[i]=1** if sum from **i** to **n** is **sum/3**, traversing the array backwards this can be done in **O(n)**.
Then just traverse again from backwards doing **suffix[i]+=suffix[i-1]**( apart from base case i=n).So now **suffix[i]** stores number of indexs **i<=j<=n** such that sum from index **j** to **n** is **sum/3**, which is what you are trying to achieve using BIT.

So what I suggest either write a bruteforce or this simple **O(n)** and check your code against it,
because as far as your approach is concerned it is correct, and debugging is something not suited for
stackoverflow.

Comment: `ans+=  (query(n, suffix) - query(i+1, suffix)); ` is this line correct i.e `i+1` and `n`

Comment: ideally it should be i not i+1

Comment: why three part one from `0 to i` and starting case only one element for 2 array `i+1` and finally `i+2 to n` so total sum from `i+2 to n`

Comment: yeah also correct that you are taking BIT 1 based index and your array 0 based index

Comment: for your approach it also be  if `dp[i]==1` so  ans+=suffix[i+2]

Comment: yeah but it will not matter if 1 to i is one part i+1 to n will never be another part because it would mean sum(1 to i)+sum(i+1,n) is total sum which is not possible because both of them are totalsum/3 so it would not matter if you do take i or i+1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68797/discussion-between-sasha-and-user4447943).

Answer (score 1):

First, we calculate an array `dp`, with dp[i] = sum from 0 to i, this can be done in O(n)

```
long[]dp = new long[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   dp[i] = a[i];
   if(i > 0)
     dp[i] += dp[i - 1];
```

Second, let say the total sum of array is x, so we need to find at which position, we have dp[i] == x/3;

For each i position which have dp[i] == 2*x/3, we need to add to final result, the number of index j < i, which `dp[j] == x/3`.

```
int count = 0;
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
    if(dp[i] == x/3)
       count++;
    else if(dp[i] == x*2/3)
       result += count;
}
```

The answer is in `result`.

What wrong with your approach is,

```
    if(dp[i]==1)
    {

        ans+=  (query(n, suffix) - query(i+1, suffix)); 
     // Checking For the Sum/3 in array where index>i+1
    }
```

This is wrong, it should be

```
(query(n, suffix) - query(i, suffix));
```

Because, we only need to remove those from 1 to i, not 1 to i + 1.

Not only that, this part:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n-2;i++){
  //....      
}
```

Should be `i <= n - 1;`

Similarly, this part, `for(int i=n ;i>=3;i--)`, should be `i >= 1`

And first part:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     a[i]= in.nextLong();
     sum+=a[i];
}
```

Should be

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
     a[i]= in.nextLong();
     sum+=a[i];
}
```

A lot of small errors in your code, which you need to put in a lot of effort to debugging first, jumping to ask here is not a good idea.

Comment: could not get you if a position i `prefix sum= sum/3` , then i checking at position `i+2 to n` no. of suffix where sum=sum/3 and between part is bond to have sum=sum/3

Comment: @user4447943 fix that, but one thing is for the initialize part, you start index from 0 `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`, but after that, all index start from 1, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the question asked we need to find three contiguous parts in an array whose sum is the same.
I will mention the steps along with the code snippet that will solve the problem for you.

1. Get the sum of the array by doing a linear scan O(n) and compute sum/3.
2. Start scanning the given array from the end. At each index we need to store the number of ways we can get a sum equal to (sum/3) i.e. if end[i] is 3, then there are 3 subsets in the array starting from index i till n(array range) where sum is sum/3.
3. Third and final step is to start scanning from the start and find the index where sum is sum/3. On finding the index add to the solution variable(initiated to zero), end[i+2].

*The thing here we are doing is, start traversing the array from start till len(array)-3. On finding the sum, sum/3, on let say index i, we have the first half that we require.*

*Now, dont care about the second half and add to the solution variable(initiated to zero) a value equal to end[i+2]. end[i+2] tells us the total number of ways starting from i+2 till the end, to get a sum equal to sum/3 for the third part.*

*Here, what we have done is taken care of the first and the third part, doing which we have also taken care of the second part which will be by default equal to sum/3. Our solution variable will be the final answer to the problem.*

Given below are the code snippets for better understanding of the above mentioned algorithm::-

*Here we are doing the backward scanning to store the number of ways to get sum/3 from the end for each index.*

```
long long int *end = (long long int *)calloc(numbers, sizeof(long long int);
long long int temp = array[numbers-1];
if(temp==sum/3){
    end[numbers-1] = 1;
}
for(i=numbers-2;i>=0;i--){
    end[i] = end[i+1];
    temp += array[i];
    if(temp==sum/3){
        end[i]++;
    }
}
```

*Once we have the end array we do the forward loop and get our final solution*

```
long long int solution = 0;
temp = 0;
for(i=0;i<numbers-2;i++){
    temp+= array[i];
    if(temp==sum/3){
        solution+=end[i+2];
    }
}
```

*solution* stores the final answer i.e. the number of ways to split the array into three contiguous parts having equal sum.